# Displaying unicode symbols using pygame

Tags: python, unicode, pygame

I've checked other answers, but cant see why my code incorrectly displays ♔.

[This is what I currently see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tNIK.png)
[image]

Here is the relevant code about the text rendering.

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Tahoma', 80, False, False)
queenblack = "♔"
queenblacktext = font.render(queenblack, True, BLACK)
screen.blit(queenblacktext, [80, 80])
pygame.display.flip()
```

All help us appreciated, thanks. Im using python 3.8, and using Pycharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unicode character is not provided by the "Tahoma" font.

Use the **"segoeuisymbol"** font if your system supports it:

```py
seguisy80 = pygame.font.SysFont("segoeuisymbol", 80)
```

Note, the supported fonts can be print by `print(pygame.font.get_fonts())`.

Alternatively download the font [Segoe UI Symbol](https://freefontsdownload.net/free-segoeuisymbol-font-135679.htm) and create a [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font)

```py
seguisy80 = pygame.font.Font("seguisym.ttf", 80)
```

Use the font to render the sign:

```py
queenblack = "♔"
queenblacktext = seguisy80.render(queenblack, True, BLACK)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

seguisy80 = pygame.font.SysFont("segoeuisymbol", 80)
queenblack = "♔"
queenblacktext = seguisy80.render(queenblack, True, BLACK)

run = True
while run:  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(WHITE)
    window.blit(queenblacktext, (100, 100))
    pygame.display.flip()
```