# Pygame image transparency confusion

Tags: python, image, pygame, alpha, pygame-surface

I have read the top 20 posts relating to this issue here, read many examples on Google, tried using `.convert()`, `.convert_alpha()`, tried with neither, tried with .png, .gif, tried with the top 5 different images on google. Please someone help me figure out how to make the pieces show with a transparent background.
Here is ALL the code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
print("1")
screen_size = (600, 600)
blue = (100, 225, 225)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Chess")


class SpriteSheet:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        """Load the sheet."""
        try:
            self.sheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert.alpha()
        except pygame.error as e:
            print(f"Unable to load spritesheet image: {filename}")
            raise SystemExit(e)


    def image_at(self, rectangle, colorkey = None):
        """Load a specific image from a specific rectangle."""
        # Loads image from x, y, x+offset, y+offset.
        rect = pygame.Rect(rectangle)
        image = pygame.Surface(rect.size)
        image.blit(self.sheet, (0, 0), rect)
        if colorkey is not None:
            if colorkey == -1:
                colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
            image.set_colorkey(colorkey, pygame.RLEACCEL)
        return image

    def images_at(self, rects, colorkey = None):
        """Load a whole bunch of images and return them as a list."""
        return [self.image_at(rect, colorkey) for rect in rects]

    def load_strip(self, rect, image_count, colorkey = None):
        """Load a whole strip of images, and return them as a list."""
        tups = [(rect[0]+rect[2]*x, rect[1], rect[2], rect[3])
                for x in range(image_count)]
        return self.images_at(tups, colorkey)
print("2")

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.playing = False
        self.move = 0
        self.player_turn = 1
        self.quit = False

    def quit(self):
        self.quit = True

print("3")
class Piece:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sprite = None
        self.spacial = [0, 0, 0]
        self.temporal = [0, 0]
        self.position = [self.spacial, self.temporal]
        self.color = ""
        self.type = ""

print("4")
chess_image = SpriteSheet('ChessPiecesArray.png')
colors = ["White", "Black"]
types = ["K", "Q", "B", "N", "R", "P"]
rect_piece = (0, 0, 133, 133)

print("5")


class ChessSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.set = []

    def create_set(self):
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(6):
                this_piece = Piece()
                this_piece.color = colors[i]
                this_piece.type = types[j]
                rect_set = (133*j, 133*i, 133*(j+1), 133*(i+1))
                this_piece.sprite = SpriteSheet.image_at(chess_image, rect_set)
                self.set.append(this_piece)

print("6")
chess = Game()
set_one = ChessSet()
set_one.create_set()

print("7")
while not chess.quit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                chess.quit()
    screen.fill(blue)
    screen.blit(set_one.set[0].sprite, (10, 10))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Here are a few images I spent time trying:

[image]

[image]

[image]
EDIT: Here is the screenshot of my error message over my code with the suggested change
[image: Changed code]

Comment: I ran the image through a transparency tool and it still didnt work, Ive tried with multiple images and tools and cannot get it to work

Comment: For some reason the image links I had originally weren't showing but they are now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an image with a transparent background. Be careful and do not download a preview of an image with a checkered background. Just because they are PNGs doesn't mean the background is transparent. The background can still be opaque. Use the following image

[image]

---

If you copy a transparent *Surface* to another *Surface* the target *Surface* has to provide transparency respectively per pixel alpha.

You can enable additional functions when creating a new surface. Set the [`SRCALPHA`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) flag to create a surface with an image format that includes a per-pixel alpha.  The initial value of the pixels is (0, 0, 0, 0):

```py
my_surface = pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

and adapt the method `image_at` of the class `SpriteSheet`. Use `pygame.SRCALPHA`:

```py
class SpriteSheet:
    # [...]

    def image_at(self, rectangle, colorkey = None):
        """Load a specific image from a specific rectangle."""
        # Loads image from x, y, x+offset, y+offset.
        rect = pygame.Rect(rectangle)
        
        image = pygame.Surface(rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA) # <----
        
        image.blit(self.sheet, (0, 0), rect)
        if colorkey is not None:
            if colorkey == -1:
                colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
            image.set_colorkey(colorkey, pygame.RLEACCEL)
        return image
```

Or use [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha):

```py
class SpriteSheet:
    # [...]

    def image_at(self, rectangle, colorkey = None):
        """Load a specific image from a specific rectangle."""
        # Loads image from x, y, x+offset, y+offset.
        rect = pygame.Rect(rectangle)
        
        image = pygame.Surface(rect.size).convert_alpha() # <----
        image.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))                          # <---
        
        image.blit(self.sheet, (0, 0), rect)
        if colorkey is not None:
            if colorkey == -1:
                colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
            image.set_colorkey(colorkey, pygame.RLEACCEL)
        return image
```

See also:

- [How can I make an Image with a transparent Backround in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623341/how-can-i-make-an-image-with-a-transparent-backround-in-pygame/62623422#62623422)
- [How do I blit a PNG with some transparency onto a surface in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634208/how-do-i-blit-a-png-with-some-transparency-onto-a-surface-in-pygame/64630678#64630678)

---

Note that chess pieces can also be drawn through a Unicode text.
See [Displaying unicode symbols using pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398332/displaying-unicode-symbols-using-pygame/63398488#63398488)

Comment: The issue still is not solved. Even with the library imported and loading the suggested function is not working.

Comment: @BrandonMartin It works fine for me. Note, you can just use one of your images. Just 1 of your images is transparent. Your code works fine. All you've to do ist to add `pygame.SRCALPHA`. I think you're just kidding me.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my updated code and error message. I want it to work, and I would accept the answer if it was working. I'm still posting on the question because I am a noob that reads the documentation, looks like the function SHOULD be working, but isn't for some reason. I'm sure I am just missing something dumb, but it is certainly not working for me.

Comment: @BrandonMartin I've no idea why your pygame version doesn't support  `SRCALPHA`. What is your pygame version? Anyway I've provided an alternative solution with `convert_alpha()`/`fill()`. See the answer.